# Create dll from existing VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: vb.net, dll

At the moment I am migrating several projects from Visual Studio 2015 to Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition.

One of them is a VB.NET project, ODKWrapper, which provides a dll for other projects. The output path is specified, it should be created in ../Run/Release.
In VisualStudio2015 it worked well.

When I build the same project in Visual Studio 2017, no dll is generated and, even worse, a dll copied to the directory is deleted.

How can I create a dll from an existing project in Visual Studio 2017?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a non-zero cost to breaking with standard build practices.  Beyond there not being a perceivable reason to do so, the odds that you can get any help with it keels over some rainy day in the future are too low.

Comment: What messages are generated in the output? What is the "Build output path" set to?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. When moving from VisualStudio2015 to VisualStudio 2017, the reference to log4net was lost. I had reset it and the project was all OK, but apparently on the wrong version of log4net. Now I've reconnected this reference and compiled as .dll works.
Many thanks for your help.